# Why Gzip compression not work in aws-elasticbeanstalk + nginx + tomcat environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gzip

The system is up and running in elasticbeanstalk here is added configs in the .ebextensions folder (located in folder root)

nginx-proxy.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    GzipCompression: 'true'
    ProxyServer: nginx
```

gzip.config

```
files:
        /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf:
        content: |
                gzip on;
                gzip_types application/json application/xml text/html text/xml text/plain application/javascript text/css;
                gzip_vary on;
```

Tried with tomcat-settings.config too, but the result is the same

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    GzipCompression: 'true'
    ProxyServer: nginx
```

only getting these response headers yet

```
cache-control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-type →application/json
date →Mon, 31 Jan 2022 08:31:22 GMT
expires →0
pragma →no-cache
server →nginx/1.20.0
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
vary →Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →DENY
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block
```

Application properties file

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
```

Tried by adding this header for postman too

```
'accept-encoding: gzip'
```

Comment: Within you request are you sending [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header? Maybe that is missing and thats why the server is not responding with gzip compression.

Comment: yes, added in application properties file. question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its works after apply this

```
@Bean
public Filter compressingFilter() {
    CompressingFilter compressingFilter = new CompressingFilter();
    return compressingFilter;
}
```

dependency used this one

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.pjl-comp-filter</groupId>
        <artifactId>pjl-comp-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

work as a charm :-)